# AngularJS Dropdown Always in Open State

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, menu, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am developing my first App with AngularJS. I am trying to create a Dropdown menu, but unable to bring it under control. Here is the html:

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This does give me the desired output as shown below:

[image]

but the dropdown is always open, instead of toggling.

Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong?

======= Here are the header files =========

```
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/mobile-angular-ui-base.min.css" />
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="dist/js/mobile-angular-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Required to use $swipe, $drag and Translate services -->
  <script src="dist/js/mobile-angular-ui.gestures.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, What is the version of ui-bootstrap i am asking.

Comment: I am using mobile-angular-ui which I believe bootstrap. Let me add the links above (I am confused about these also)

Comment: Everything works. Just use last versions of bootstrap and angular ui

Comment: Here is a broken plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/JGcoF4?p=preview

Comment: @Anatoli You mean I should not be using http://mobileangularui.com/ ?

Comment: Your link is broken, because you need to create (var app = angular.module("App", [])). And you need to connect bootstrap's libraries

Comment: You need to link angular, angular ui and bootstrap. And after check, whether it works. Maybe, the problem is in versions of libraries that mobileangularui uses.

Comment: I have added var app = angular.module("App", []))
Which libraries do I need to add/remove please? I am totally new to AngularJS/Bootstrap

Comment: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Comment: [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: I have updated the code as you have advised. I can now see a formatted button. But clicking on it doesn't pull down the dropdown :-( http://plnkr.co/edit/JGcoF4?p=preview

Comment: And link jquery before using Angular UI

Comment: Yep! Many thanks! It works now. But I wanted to avoid JQuery. I already have my App build with JQMobile and I wanted to shift to AngularJS + Bootstrap. Secondly why I am not getting output for <p>Hello {{username}}!</p>

Comment: You have not added angularjs in the scripts.

Comment: You can't avoid using jQuery because you use animation that based on jquery

Comment: Added angularjs. Still doesn't work

Comment: check console in your browser

Comment: maybe some syntax error

Comment: Remove the extra ')' and remove the ui-bootsrap dependency or load the corresponding js. Also as @Anatoli mentioned, checking the console is a good idea. In chrome and mozila ctrl+shift+i will display the developer tools.

Comment: Thanks @paje007. That worked :)
I am really thankful to both of you for your prompt help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer on your question is using last versions of Angular+jQuery+Bootstrap+Angular UI.

Comment: Accepting this answer only indicates that your help in above comments solved the problem.